# Transformer and MOSFET combination not working

Tags: transformer, oscillator, h-bridge, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I am working to understand the circuit of a vibrating needle used in factories to scratch a mark on a soft surface. Essentially, this circuit drives a MOSFET bridge which then drives a Transformer. Output of the transformer goes to the needle. The needle vibrates, and hence any surface can be cleaned using this needle.

The input comes from TP7: 4.8V when OFF and 0.5V when ON.
TP7 results in voltage at TP8: 0V when OFF and 22V when ON.
TP8 goes to transformer, probably its main primary voltage.
The two ICs U30 (programmable oscillator) and U41 (MOSFET driver) go to TP10 and TP11 and drive Q43 and Q44 - whose purpose I do not know.

I am facing trouble understanding this circuit.

The doubts I have are - 
What is the transformer doing?
What kind of transformer is this one? (here is how the board looks like)

[image: Board image]

What is the purpose of Q41 and Q42?
What is the purpose of Q53?

[image: Modified circuit to highlight the parts]

This is how the hand-piece/needle looks like. There is a needle connected to its leftmost end. This probe connects to the output port of PCB by means of a connector.

[image: Handpiece photograph]

Comment: I don't see Q43 and Q44 - maybe you can amend the picture with a red circle around them? There are two transformers in the schematic - make it clear which one you refer to.

Comment: Could we see the needle and how this interacts with the rest of the device?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Edited the schematic and board image and re-uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a high voltage controlled power tool used as an engraver. These often have diamond tips.

[image]

There is a current limiter of 2.1A on 24Vdc and a FET complementary drive to a centre-tapped boost transformer.  Thus it draws less than 50W.

PWM control is a guess, although it could be frequency control for resonance.
Piezo is just a guess too.

The electronics are similar to a high-frequency AC Boost transformer with AC coupled output.  That suggests to me it is a Piezo load.

Comment: That is convincing, as the inner part of that hand-piece contain crystal so likely it is a piezo load. To add, the TP10 and TP11 give 0V when disabled (same time when TP7 is at 4.8V) and they give constant 5.6V when enabled (same time when TP7 is at 1.5V). I have observed that the needle vibration increases when TP7 is taken from 4.8V to 1.5V - kind of a Power Setting. The transformer has coil turn ratio 1:1.2.

Comment: Ideally, TP8 goes from 0V to 22V when TP7 is taken from 4.8V to 1.5V. But for this board TP8 constantly gives 0V. What could be the issue? Is Q53 necessary? Does NF loop cause oscillation?

Comment: 2.1 is close to cutoff =~3*0.7 so 1.5 would enable is lower,,maybe I had the Disable high reversed??

Comment: It performs approximately linearly between the input range of 4.8 to 1.5. The lower the input (TP7), the higher the output (TP8). So it is not binary like On and Off, it is continuous. Does Q53 resist or counter the signal at TP7?

Comment: yes of course as it attenuates a negative feedback loop, I just missed an inversion somewhere. the arrows show the polarity of incremental voltage